# knockout js inserting extra empty element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js

I have a list of reviews that I'm binding to a ul > li and for some reason Knockout js is inserting a blank empty

for each of the items, along with the bound li.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong that makes this occur? Just need to get the extra empty li to stop being inserted. I've tried to play with the bindings, but I don't see what is causing this.

```
<ul id="reviews-list" data-bind="foreach: reviews">
     <li data-bind="click:$parent.selectReview">
         <h1 data-bind="text: title"></h1>
        <p class="review-meta"><span data-bind="text: status, css: $data.status"></span><span class="pull-right" data-bind="text: date_published"></p>
    <li>
</ul>
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
 function Review(data) {
    this.id             = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.title          = ko.observable(data.title);
    this.content        = ko.observable(data.content);
    this.status         = ko.observable(data.status);
    this.featured       = ko.observable(data.featured);
    this.date_created   = ko.observable(data.date_created);
    this.date_published = ko.observable(data.date_published);
    this.last_updated   = ko.observable(data.last_updated); 
}

function ReviewsViewModel() {
    // data
    var self = this;
    self.reviews = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedReview = ko.observable();

    // operations

    // load initial reviews from server
    $.getJSON('/admin/reviews/getreviews', {status : ''}, function(reviewsData) {
        var mappedReviews = $.map(reviewsData, function(review) {return new Review(review)});
        self.reviews(mappedReviews);        
    });

    self.filterReviews = function(status, label) {
        $.getJSON('/admin/reviews/getreviews', {status : status}, function(reviewsData) {
            var mappedReviews = $.map(reviewsData, function(review) {return new Review(review)});
            self.reviews(mappedReviews);
            var actionTitle = "";
            switch(status) {
                case '':
                    actionTitle = 'All Reviews';
                    break
                case 'published':
                    actionTitle = 'Published';
                    break;
                case 'draft':
                    actionTitle = 'Drafts';
                    break;
            }
            $(".action-title").html(actionTitle);
        });     
    }

    // apply css class based on the status
    self.statusCSS = function(value) {
        return value;
    }

    self.selectReview = function(r) {
        self.selectedReview(r);
        $("#review-editor").markdown({
            autofocus:false, 
            saveable:true, 
            hideable: false,
            onShow: function(e) {
                toggleEditorToolbar();
                e.showPreview();
                editor = e;
            }
        }); 
        //$("#reviews-list li").removeClass('active-review');
        $(this).addClass('active-review');          
        editMode();
        editMode();
    }
}
```

Example JSON that is used in the binding

```
[{"id":"1","title":"Danny Kane's Bishops & Barons nightclub on E. 14th St. recalls an era of bygone glamour","content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus in dapibus turpis. Nulla posuere, ipsum ac fringilla pulvinar, sapien ipsum semper eros, eget tincidunt nisl orci ac nunc. Nulla iaculis sit amet tortor non laoreet. Nulla tincidunt augue auctor ante porttitor, eget porttitor lorem dignissim. Suspendisse adipiscing, ipsum nec vestibulum ultricies, enim ligula tempus augue, et scelerisque justo sapien vitae velit. Sed in rhoncus mauris. Sed condimentum libero ipsum, id elementum ligula molestie eget. Quisque et augue elit. Aliquam condimentum a enim ullamcorper porttitor. Morbi ullamcorper magna purus, vitae auctor ante varius ac. Morbi convallis nec lorem non feugiat. Proin interdum convallis elementum. Pellentesque ipsum neque, luctus et semper quis, mattis sed odio. Proin at orci ac quam adipiscing volutpat id ac diam.","featured":"0","date_created":"2013-11-06 22:50:02","date_published":"2012-05-13 00:00:00","last_updated":"2012-05-13 00:00:00","status":"published"},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html was messed up. Try this (fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/M2phC/3/) :

```
<ul id="reviews-list" data-bind="foreach: $data">
     <li>
         <h1 data-bind="text: title"></h1>
         <p class="review-meta"><span data-bind="text: status, css: $data.status"></span><span class="pull-right" data-bind="text: date_published"></span></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The exact cause is that you somewhere at the end you had a `<li>` and you should have had a `</li>`

Comment: I love it and hate it when it something so simple. Thanks man. That's what I get for coding for 16 hours straight...time to sleep. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would edit your model to force using the correct scope -

```
function Review(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id             = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.title          = ko.observable(data.title);
    self.content        = ko.observable(data.content);
    self.status         = ko.observable(data.status);
    self.featured       = ko.observable(data.featured);
    self.date_created   = ko.observable(data.date_created);
    self.date_published = ko.observable(data.date_published);
    self.last_updated   = ko.observable(data.last_updated); 
}
```

And then watch the console to make sure all of the properties you are expecting are being populated -

ex. =

```
function Review(data) {
    var self = this;
    console.log(data.title);
    self .title          = ko.observable(data.title);
    console.log(self.title());
}
```

**EDIT**

You aren't closing your LI tag

```
 <li data-bind="click:$parent.selectReview">
     <h1 data-bind="text: title"></h1>
    <p class="review-meta"><span data-bind="text: status, css: $data.status"></span><span class="pull-right" data-bind="text: date_published"></p>
<li>
```

should be

Comment: OK. Tried that and everything is right, all expected values are present. but the generated html clearly has an extra empty li foreach li in the list.